# How do I design a custom Xamlwriter?

Tags: wpf, serialization

I feel the need to design a custom serializer for some more complex objects, but i find little help on the subject. if anyone knows of a step-by-step explanation, I would appreciate a link.

Comment: Just a little extra detail: My actual intention is to have my objects override XamlWriter's Save and Load methods and decide what properties to save and tell some inner objects save themselves in the way they decide. Thus I would one an Xaml file that will describe a tree structure of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to look for an example would be the actual XamlWriter via Reflector, ILSpy, or some such other tool. I've never gotten it to work right, but there is apparently a way to step into WPF 3.5 source code. Here is another thread on that http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/8f1cab0f-b19a-4f63-ac84-23d0403abd0f